# Open popup by clicking on iframe

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, popup

I want to open popup window by clicking on iframe. Please let me know
 how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I should not answer your question, because it lacks of own research and also is something that could have been googled in 1 minute, but here you go:

```
window.open(url, "name", "options");
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: I have googled it but havent found any solution, if you have answer then pls tell me.

Comment: Have you even tried my answer? This opens a popup of the browser, kinda like a new window. I added a link in my answer for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

**1) HTML Mark up**

```
<a href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Launch video player</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/41135183?portrait=0" width="497" height="298" seamless=""></iframe>
</div>
```

**2) JS**

```
// popup examples
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
    // The window width and height are decreased by 30 to take the tolerance of 15 pixels at each side into account
    function scale( width, height, padding, border ) {
        var scrWidth = $( window ).width() - 30,
            scrHeight = $( window ).height() - 30,
            ifrPadding = 2 * padding,
            ifrBorder = 2 * border,
            ifrWidth = width + ifrPadding + ifrBorder,
            ifrHeight = height + ifrPadding + ifrBorder,
            h, w;
        if ( ifrWidth < scrWidth && ifrHeight < scrHeight ) {
            w = ifrWidth;
            h = ifrHeight;
        } else if ( ( ifrWidth / scrWidth ) > ( ifrHeight / scrHeight ) ) {
            w = scrWidth;
            h = ( scrWidth / ifrWidth ) * ifrHeight;
        } else {
            h = scrHeight;
            w = ( scrHeight / ifrHeight ) * ifrWidth;
        }
        return {
            'width': w - ( ifrPadding + ifrBorder ),
            'height': h - ( ifrPadding + ifrBorder )
        };
    };
    $( ".ui-popup iframe" )
        .attr( "width", 0 )
        .attr( "height", "auto" );
    $( "#popupVideo" ).on({
        popupbeforeposition: function() {
            // call our custom function scale() to get the width and height
            var size = scale( 497, 298, 15, 1 ),
                w = size.width,
                h = size.height;
            $( "#popupVideo iframe" )
                .attr( "width", w )
                .attr( "height", h );
        },
        popupafterclose: function() {
            $( "#popupVideo iframe" )
                .attr( "width", 0 )
                .attr( "height", 0 );
        }
    });
});
```

**3. CSS**

```
iframe {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Way to overkill for what the OP asked for lol. Fiddle would be nice, maybe I´ll use it tho :P

Comment: Thanku raghav but its not this what i want. After clicking iframe (Youtube video) it opens popup (Modal)